system prompt to be use under llama index chatEngine
I am using llamaindex chatengine , It works okay, but the system prompt is not working .
i changed it to context_prompt as well.
But its not taking effect .
If i can get some direction where i am wrong.
 llm = Anthropic(model="claude-3-5-sonnet-20240620")

query = request.json.get('query')
memory = ChatMemoryBuffer.from_defaults(token_limit=5000)
session = request.json.get('session_id')
customer_data = request.json.get('customer_data')
host = "mongodb+srv://y? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority"
port = 27017
db_name = "data-entry"
collection_name = "experience"
query_dict = {}
field_names = ["_id", "title", "description", "address", "price", "duration", 
"availableTime", "links",
               "termsAndConditions", "storyLineKeywords", "linkWithOtherExperience"]
reader = SimpleMongoReader(host, port)
documents = reader.load_data(
    db_name, collection_name, field_names, query_dict=query_dict
)
index = SummaryIndex.from_documents(documents)

chat_engine = index.as_chat_engine(
     memory=memory,
     llm=llm,
     similarity_top_k=2,
     system_prompt=(
         "Only return the suggested experience '_id' and 'title'"
     ),
     verbose=False,
 )
response = chat_engine.chat(query)
print(response)


what error do you get?

I dont get any error , it gives the response , But its Not considering my system_prompt, What ever i write in system_prompt (as you see in my code), its not considering it

I think your problem might be your are creating an index using one model and a chat engine with another model.
By default, Llama Index uses OpenAI if no llm is specified.
So in your code, it seems you might be using OpenAI to create your index and then setting Anthropic for the chat engine.
I would try setting the llm before creating your index like this:
Settings.llm = llm


um may be , let me try

did it work in the end?

With openai it worked. But i wanted to use Anthropic , but still trying ti figure out how to use Anthropic index

you are probably using the Settings in the wrong position or you are forgetting to set the embedding model correctly.

To give system prompt you need to use as_query_engine method, you can not use chat engine

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
